# Converting JSON string into dictionary object

Tags: python, json, parsing, request

I've been able to call an api and get the response but am having trouble converting the JSON string into a Python dictionary object so I can parse through it.

Example of JSON string:

```
{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "C032A2",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-13T22:44:39Z",
    "latitude": 50.723694,
    "longitude": -114.63788,
    "altitude_baro": 13225,
    "heading": 40.0,
    "ground_speed": 340.0,
    "vertical_rate": -2360,
    "squawk_code": "6616",
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "WEN3627",
    "tail_number": "C-FTEN",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial",
    "flight_number": "WR3627",
    "origin_airport_iata": "PDX",
    "destination_airport_iata": "YYC"
  }
}{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "AB35D8",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-13T22:44:42Z",
    "latitude": 33.69842,
    "longitude": -111.896725,
    "altitude_baro": 4325,
    "heading": 260.0,
    "ground_speed": 90.0,
    "vertical_rate": -250,
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "MSQT356",
    "tail_number": "N821PA",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial"
  }
}{
```

Code I'm using, I can print out the JSON string by opening its file but I can't access it as a dictionary. Ideally, I am just trying to count the number of different dictionaries within the JSON string.

```
    #call datastream and output to new file
    def call_stream(self):
        try:
            #paramaters for call
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(self.token)}
            timeout = time.time() + self.timeout

            #calling datastream
            with requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, stream=True) as r:
                with open('datastream:' + self.get_time() + '.json', 'w') as json_file:
                    global target_updates_count
                    global terrestrial_count
                    global satellite_count
                    global FILENAME
                    FILENAME.append(json_file.name)

                    #reading through JSON hashtables
                    for line in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
                        target_updates_count += 1
                        if time.time() < timeout:
                            msg = json.loads(line)
                            json_pprint = json.dumps(msg)
                            json_file.write(json_pprint)

                            #looping through dict objects and counting useful statistics for target_updates
                            data = msg['target']
                            for key in data:
                                if key == 'collection_type' and data[key] == 'terrestrial':
                                    terrestrial_count += 1
                                elif key == 'collection_type' and data[key] == 'satellite':
                                    satellite_count += 1
                        else:
                            r.close()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Comment: The data you got from the server was perfectly usable for parsing, as you proved yourself. Just save that directly. It's the pretty printing and the removal of line breaks in between that made this difficult for you.

Comment: FYI, you can use `json.dump(json_file, msg)` to write the JSON directly to the file, instead of dumping to a string and then writing the string to the file.

Comment: that makes sense, I previously parsed it and couldn't use the same logic. Thanks, will parse the original return file.

Comment: Why not use the `json` module to parse it, or, even better, simply call the `.json()` method on the result of the `requests.get()`.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't put multiple JSON objects in a file. Put them all in a list, then convert the list to JSON and write the whole thing to the file.

Comment: @AlexHall The sample data is NOT a JSON string, but rather several JSON hashtables concatenated together. Whatever code that creates the files should output the hash tables as an array of hash tables instead.

Comment: can someone show what is being said in my code as an example, sorry I'm a beginner to all of this.

Comment: zstar: As @blhsing said, the data you're getting isn't valid JSON format, so trying to convert to a dictionary object with simple `json.loads()` calls like you are doing isn't going to work.

Comment: I don't think it's the server sending the data wrong, it looks like zstar converting each line in data into json object and parsing the same thing as string and then writing to file?

Comment: @Guven: Well, we'll never know unless zstar updates the question and puts in an exact copy of the JSON string being received.

Comment: the above worked for me.

Comment: I updated with what works for me to access the line's as a dictionary